# Are same static variables used for each recursive call to a function?

Tags: c, recursion, static

As per my understanding, each called function has some memory allocated to it in the program stack, and this holds true even if the same function calls itself recursively (i.e, each invocation has it's own memory in program stack). Please answer the following two questions arising from my program below:

If a variable is declared static in a function, will the same variable/same copy be used for all recursive calls of that function?

If the variable is not declared static (e.g, simply "int x"), will each recursive call to the function have its own copy of that variable? If yes, is that the way it normally happens when a function is called from other function, including the recursive calls?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    static int x=0;
    x++;
    printf("Team %d\n",x);
    if(x<10)
        main();
    else
        exit;
}
```

**Output:**

```
Team 1
Team 2
Team 3
Team 4
Team 5
Team 6
Team 7
Team 8
Team 9
Team 10
```

Comment: You already have your answer in the output. Do you have any doubts still?

Comment: What @RSahu said, why not continue to test it out for yourself.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Only in C++ in C it is not undefined to call main, although I would not recommend it.

Comment: But you should absolutely avoid doing it anyway.

Comment: @RSahu Why else do you think I posted the question?Isn't it obvious that I still had doubts? The three people who were nice enough to answer may not have as much reputation as you have, but were way more helpful.And yeah, thanks for the downvote.

Comment: @Newbie I voted to close the question since it's a duplicate but I did not downvote. Please don't make assumptions that are not true and hold a grudge based on those assumptions. I hope we meet again in a different question with a more positive interaction.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> If a variable is declared static in a function, will the same
>   variable/same copy be used for all recursive calls of that function?

Yes, as your code sample shows

> If the variable is not declared static (e.g, simply "int x"), will
>   each recursive call to the function have its own copy of that
>   variable? If yes, is that the way it normally happens when a function
>   is called from other function, including the recursive calls?

Yes, each call will have it's own stack frame with a copy of each local variable. This is what happens for every function call, whether they are recursive or not. And yes, this very principle allows, among other things, recursion.

Comment: Thank you. You understood every bit of what I wanted to ask and answered that in detail.

Answer (score 8):

Static variables live the life of the program, there is only one copy

Locals (Autos) get a new copy on the stack each function call.

Parameters passed by value get a new copy as well.

Parameters passed by reference (pointer) point to the copy that's passed to them. Therefore if it's a local in a recursive execution, it might be a unique copy; but usually it's a reference to a variable that called the function before the recursion started, therefore, the same copy.

It's better to do the functionality you're doing by passing a pointer to a variable, you have more control over subsequent instances of recursion.

Answer (score 4):

Your understanding fairly accurate.

`static` means there is one version of the variable. Each time a function is called that contains a `static` variable the variable will have the last value assigned to it. A global variable can also be marked `static` which means its scope is limited to that file.

When a function is called its local variables are placed on the call stack. This stack is pushed for each function call and then popped when each function exists. A recursive call just keeps pushing a new copy of the same function onto the stack.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer.